# Knockout observable array Change Event

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have an `observableArray` with `observable properties`. I want to set status of observableArray item whenever item added/any property of item get changed.

```
function ViewModel() {
this.myArray=ko.observableArray([]);
}
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $(function(){
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        viewModel.myArray.push({Value1:ko.observable("Test"),Value2:ko.observable("Test1"),Status:ko.observable('Added')});

});
```

Whenever `observableArray` item will get modified`(From UI or from Code)` i want to `fire change event` with that item.

**Ex:-** Modified from code

```
viewModel.myArray()[0].Value1("newTest1");  // At this point i need change event with changed array item.
```

Please suggest how i can achieve this. Your effort will be appreciated.

Comment: changes made to observableArray(delete/add) will be notified not to there internal content see sample here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27274/ .

Comment: IF this array is binded with HTML and user changes the value from UI then it will automatically update the observableArray. I want to change the status of that item from Added to Modified. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: yes there is , let me get a fiddle for you . idea is simple rather subscribing on observableArray trying subscribing at child level (observable) .

Comment: something like this let me know http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27277/ . cheers

Comment: You make my weekend cheers :-). Can you post this as answer so that i will close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments above you need to subscribe to `observable` rather trying to subscribe on observableArray (as it get notified only when something added/deleted) .

**viewModel:**

```
function child(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Value1 = ko.observable(data.Value1);
    self.Value2 = ko.observable(data.Value2);
    self.Status = ko.observable(data.Status);
    ko.computed(function () {
        self.Value1();
        self.Value2(); // subscribing multiple observables
        if (!ko.computedContext.isInitial()) { //status remains intact initially(onLoad)
            self.Status('Modified');
        }
    });
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.myArray = ko.observableArray([]);
}
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

working sample up **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27279/)**

You can find above i am using `computedContext` with function `isInitial`

> isInitial() — A function that returns true if called during the first
>   ever evaluation of the current computed observable, or false
>   otherwise. For pure computed observables, isInitial() is always
>   undefined.

computed documentation [**here**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some (private) computed field where you will iterate through all observable properties you need. 
When something will change later on this computed, it will be recomputed and you will get a notification

```
ko.computed(function(){
    viewModel.collection().forEach(function(element){
        var a = element.text();
    });
}
```

In this example when an array is changed or any element text is changed the entire compute is recomputed, and here you can set some status that you need

Comment: IF this array is binded with HTML and user changes the value from UI then it will automatically update the observableArray. I want to change the status of that item from Added to Modified. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use observable.subscribe (for example text.subscribe) and update status there

Comment: Another way - you can make status a computed field which will compare current value and the initial one and return a corresponding status